# Conversion of string array element to int in c++ using stoi()?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, type-conversion, int

I have a piece of code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
string s[5];

s[0] = "Hello";
s[1] = "12345";

cout << s[0] << " " << s[1] << "\n"; 
cout << s[0][0] << " " << s[1][1] << "\n";

int y = stoi(s[1]);          //This does not show an error
cout <<"y is "<< y << "\n";
//int x = stoi(s[1][1]);       //This shows error
//cout <<"x is "<< x << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Hello 12345  
H 2  
y is 12345
```

But it shows an error when I uncomment

```
int x = stoi(s[1][0]);
cout <<"x is "<< x << "\n";
```

If in both the cases a `string` is being converted to `int` using `stoi()` 
function then why do the later part of code gives an error?
I have tried the same using `atoi(s[1][0].c_str())` but it also gives an error.

What is the alternative for this, if I want to convert the second type of elements to int?

Comment: What according to you `s[1][0]` refers to?

Comment: It should be a string element I guess. @AditiRawat

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: As for your problem, `s[1]` is a `std::string`, and `s[1][0]` is a single *character* in the string `s[1]`. There's no overload of [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which takes a single character.

Comment: Umm let me put it this way.. `char s [2]` is an array of 2 elements...`char arr [3][2]`  is array of 3 elements of type `char [2]`. It is 2nd dimension.

Comment: If it's a `character` then either of `atoi()` or `atoi(s[1][0])` should work, but they are also also not working. :( What may be the alternative for this problem? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: No, all the functions are for converting ***strings*** containing numbers.

Comment: It is not solution with stoi but maybe also useful try to int y = s[1][0] - '0'; to convert ascii number to int

Comment: @NickS -- `s[1][0] - '0'` converts a decimal digit to the corresponding integer value **regardless of the character encoding**. So it's true that it works for ASCII, but there's no need to assume ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s[1]` is a `std::string`, so `s[1][0]` is a single `char` in that string.

Calling `std::stoi()` with a `char` as input doesn't work because it takes only a `std::string` as input, and `std::string` doesn't have a constructor that takes just a single `char` as input.

To do what you are attempting, you need to do this instead:

```
int x = stoi(string(1, s[1][0]));
```

Or

```
int x = stoi(string(&(s[1][0]), 1));
```

Your call to `atoi()` doesn't work because you are trying to call `c_str()` on a single `char` instead of the `std::string` it belongs to, eg:

```
int x = atoi(s[1].c_str());
```

Comment: So, this cannot be implemented using atoi()? `int x = atoi(s[1][0])` is also not working?

Comment: Yes, atoi works fine. `int x = atoi(&s[1][0])`. I was forgetting the "&". Thanks a lot, I learnt something today :)

Comment: @sarthak-sopho `atoi()` expects a null-terminated C-style string as input, you can't pass it a single `char` unless you copy it to a `char[2]` first, where `[0]` is the character and `[1]` is zero

Answer (score -1):

**[stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) has as input a string not a char.**
Try this:

```
string str(s[0][0]);
int y = stoi(str);
```

Comment: `std::string` does not have a 1-parameter constructor that accepts a `char` as input